# Angular 2 Http Post Error | JSON

Tags: angular

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.

**Angular2 post code**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Please always post your code as *code* in your question as well as any error messages :)

Comment: Please read up on how to ask a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, use `URLSearchParams` instead;

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

and inside your post function, do not send your object `body`, instead do this:

```
let postBody = new URLSearchParams();
postBody.set('yourProperty1', body.yourProperty1);
postBody.set('yourProperty12', body.yourProperty2);
...

return this._htpp.post('yourUrl', postBody, options)
  .map(...)
```